# How to write a for loop that skips elements if they are equal to the next index in an array list?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have an array list containing a list of liked things collected from users. for example, atmosphere, open area, spacious, etc.

now I am getting these values from my firestore DB and saving them in the `arrayList<String>`. if more than one user said they liked the atmosphere I want to display different things they liked in my app's reviews page and not the same things over and over.

how to write a for loop that will skip elements if they are equal and initialize my TextView with values that are not equal to each other?

I made things work for the first TextView and the second textView to be unique but how will I make the third textView also a unique value from my ArrayList?

heres what i've done so far:

```
private ArrayList<String> allLikes;
for(int i = 0; i<allLikes.size()-1; i++){
     if(allLikes.get(i) != allLikes.get(i+1)){
        liked1.setText(allLikes.get(i));
        liked2.setText(allLikes.get(i+1));
        // liked3.setText(allLikes.get(i+2)); //this line is causing an error.
        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "NOT EQUAL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }else{
        liked1.setText(allLikes.get(0));
        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "EQUAL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}
```

Comment: What is the error for that line?

Comment: @TheLegend42 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 12

Comment: What is the `String` in `allLikes`? Is it a list of all users who liked some specific thing, or is it a list of things liked by a specific user? Either way, it seems like you simply want to remove duplicates, so `new LinkedHashSet(allLikes)` will return a collection of distinct "likes" (users or things, whichever the list contains) in the order of when that "like" was first seen. Alternatively, use a `TreeSet` if you want the "likes" sorted lexicographically.

Comment: Of course you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, since you're iterating *all* values, so when you check the "next" value of the last value, there is no such thing. You need to decide what that means, then code it.

Comment: Just fetch a new list that removes the duplicates from the list before your `for` loop: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: check the length of `allLikes` before getting `i+1 and i+2`

Comment: @Andreas yes i know how do i fix that?

Comment: @Mohamed I already [told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698840/how-to-write-a-for-loop-that-skips-elements-if-they-are-equal-to-the-next-index?noredirect=1#comment112640690_63698840), but let me expand that, so you might better understand: *You* need to decide how to handle the last value, where your normal check against the "next" value will fail to find such a value, then *add code to handle it!*

Comment: awesome @Andreas please any detailed answer? that would be much better. coding is not language like english, so you need to show me an example.

Comment: @Mohamed Conditional logic to handle something different is usually done with an `if` statement, i.e. "if this is last value then do something different". Are you saying you can't figure out if you're processing the last value, by comparing the index `i` against the size of the list?

Comment: and please this is a coding website, dont use coding principals with the english language... "if this is last value then do something different" has no meaning in programming languages. that is not java that is english

Comment: if it were that simple ill just type  "if this is last value then do something different" in my android studio and run it and it would understand and give me my desired outcome lol

Comment: Because if you can write code like shown in the question, you should already have learned how to write a simple `if` statement comparing `i` to the last index position of the list, i.e. `allLikes.size()-1`, or since you want to access the following 2 values, compare against `allLikes.size()-2`. In short, `if (i < allLikes.size()-2) { /* handle normally */ } else { /* there aren't 2 more values, so do something different */ }` --- Or change the `for` loop to stop at `allLikes.size()-2`, i.e. `for(int i = 0; i<allLikes.size()-2; i++)`, **so `get(i + 2)` doesn't exceed the list size**.

Comment: @Andreas i already did that, i want to set three values not two.

Comment: @Andreas yeah i know that but when im doing it this way it still gives me two values of the same string and one value different, i need all three to be different\\

Comment: The logic of your code is very unclear about what you're trying to. You need to edit the question and clarify it. E.g. the code iterates a list and sets the text for `liked1` on every iteration, which means that only the value from the last iteration will be displayed, so what the point of the loop. --- Also, it seem you want to display the current element and the next two elements, if there are all different, exception you only compare the first 2 of the 3 values.

Comment: What do you want the end result to be for inputs such as `["A", "B", "C", "B", "D", "E"]`? Since you're loop overrides previous values, only the  "B", "D", "E" set of values matter, so `B, D, E, NOT EQUAL`? Even though there are equal values earlier in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this pattern:

```
private ArrayList<String> allLikes = null;
//fill your list
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(allLikes);
int i=0;
for (Iterator<String> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String s= it.next();
    i++;
    if (i==1)
        textView1.setText(s);
    else if (i==2)
        textView2.setText(s);
    else if (i==3)
        textView3.setText(s);
    else
        break;
}
```

When you convert a `List` to a `Set`, all the similar entries are removed.

Comment: i have 3 as mentioned above in the quesetion @sajjad

Comment: So what do you want to do exactly? Setting the first 3 values of your list in `TextView`s?

Comment: this method didnt work for me.. its giving me exact same strings for all three text views. is there a way to do this with a for loop?

Comment: setting 3 values from my array list that are not equal to each other @Sajjad

Comment: Edited my answer. According to what you said, this should do the job.